# How to add and remove class from a matched element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the basic **html** structure:

```
<div class="modern">
  <button type="button">Modern</button>
</div>
<div class="recent">
  <button type="button"><Recent</button>
</div>

<svg>
  <path class="modern">A</path>
  <path class="recent">B</path>
  <path class="recent">C</path>
  <path class="modern">D</path>
  <path class="recent">E</path>
</svg>
```

Then on **js** once I click I check if any path has the same class as per the `.parent` of the clicked element, and if so add a class fadeIn to each matched element and fade it in sequentially. If not, add a class FadeOut and fade out the paths sequentially.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
  var periodClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
  var gapBetweenEach = 200;
  var speedOfFade = 400;
  $("svg path").each(function(i, path) {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).attr('class', cl.includes(periodClass) ? cl + ' fadeIn' : cl.replace(/fadeIn/g, 'fadeOut'))
    $(".fadeIn").delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeIn(speedOfFade);
    $(".fadeOut").delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeOut(speedOfFade);
  });
});
```

The above works but when I start clicking on the different buttons the classes keeps been added and the whole logic of fadeIn and fadeOut sequentially gets broken.

These are the classes I get after a few clicks

```
fadeOut fadeOut fadeIn
```

Comment: You can use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` jQuery methods

Comment: There is a bit of more logic to it then simply add remove class i reckon

Comment: @rob.m no, those functions do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can jQuery [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) methods

```
$("svg path").each(function(i, path) {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.hasClass(periodClass)) {
        elem.removeClass('fadeOut').addClass('fadeIn');
    } else {
        elem.removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut');
    }

    //Rest of your code ...
    $(".fadeIn").delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeIn(speedOfFade);
    $(".fadeOut").delay(gapBetweenEach * i).fadeOut(speedOfFade);
});
```

Comment: thanks now works, I had tried the code before you edited it